# Wordpress URLs changed to relative on transferring server

Tags: urls

I have developed a Wordpress site on staging server. It is working absolutely fine.

When I moved the site to live server, media upload URLs changed to relative.

Staging media URL as image source:

```
<img src="http://staging.myurl.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/featured-bg-150x150.jpg">
```

Live media URL as image source:

```
<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/featured-bg-150x150.jpg">
```

Did I need to take care of something while moving site? Or this issue may be server dependent.

Another cause what I think can be from the SEO plugin installed, I'm not sure about this.

**Note:** Both servers are at different domains.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you do when you moved it? Did you follow this or any other guide? http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress It's very hard to help with such limited information.

Comment: @GhostToast: I've done it hundred times, with no issue. I've already followed the link you shared. To my surprise this happen first time. What information you want me to share with you?

Comment: Is your new server running `mod_pagespeed` by any chance?

Comment: @s_ha_dum: I've no idea, How would I know about this?

Comment: [`phpinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php). It is a bit of a long shot but some of the pagespeed rules do strip domain names.

Comment: I've checked that, There isn't any such module installed on server.